# Is there a better way to show the pause hover in this simple slideshow?

Tags: jquery

Is there a better way to **add the hover** to this simple slideshow. I want the div to fade in like this to show it's paused and this was the only way I could come up with. I'm still learning jQuery.

This is the 24hr DEMO: http://trialsites.ihoststudio.com/trialsite366742/website/

***Note*** *Doesn't effect this but it's done in a wysiwyg program so the html is limited*

css:

```
#pause { 
display: none;
width: 70px;
background: white; 
padding: 2px;
border-radius: 6px;
border:1px solid black; 
font:15px/1.1em arial;
color: black;
text-align:center;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
var intervalId;
$("#A > div:gt(0)").hide();
startInterval();
$('#A > div').mouseover(function() { stopInterval(); });
$('#A > div').mouseout(function() { startInterval(); });
$('#A > div').hover(
function() { $('#pause').fadeIn(); },
function() { $('#pause').fadeOut(); }
);

function stopInterval() {
clearInterval(intervalId);
}

function startInterval() {
intervalId = setInterval(function() {
$("#A > div:first")
.fadeOut(1000)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#A');
}, 3000);
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to add .stop() to your animations.

```
$('#pause').stop().fadeIn();
```

Read this for reference:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

You might also want to consider changing this:

```
$('#A > div').mouseover(function() { stopInterval(); });
$('#A > div').mouseout(function() { startInterval(); });
$('#A > div').hover(
function() { $('#pause').fadeIn(); },
function() { $('#pause').fadeOut(); }
);
```

To this:

```
    $('#A > div').hover(
        function() { stopInterval(); $('#pause').fadeIn(); },
        function() { startInterval(); $('#pause').fadeOut(); }
    );
```

Comment: **Excellent** M I tried it the opposite way and didn't put the ; before .fadeIn in mousover (thought it wasn't needed there) and had to settle.  Thanks for the stop() tip...